# iPod Nano 6th Generation stuck power button

Tags: ipod-nano

I heard that you can start the iPod Nano using the volume keys in lieu of the stuck power key. Is this true? Any other way around the stuck power button?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Plug it into your computer or a power source. It will power up; unplug it  and you can start the music or audiobook or whathave you. When you want to stop, you can pull out the headphone which shuts it down. To restart, you'll have to do the same and it won't start at the point where you stopped. I know it isn't great, but it is something. I will eventually take it apart and try to do the repair that is posted on the internet.